# Вопрос по callback_data

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Возможно как нибудь данный callback handler переделать так, чтобы он работал с text_startswith (ну или что нибудь подобное)? Главное, чтобы не применялось lambda call: True

Просто у меня уже много кода написано с коллбэками в которых text_startswith. И получается, что если сделать lambda call: True, то другие хэндлеры перестают работать.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True) # Inline часть
async def cal(call, state: FSMContext):
    if 'ans' in call.data:
        a = call.data.index('-ans')
        ids = call.data[:a]
        await call.message.answer('Введите ответ пользователю:', reply_markup=kb.back)
        await st.item2.set() # админ отвечает пользователю
        await state.update_data(uid=ids)
```

Кнопка

```
  types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ответить', callback_data=f'{user_id}-ans')
```

Comment: используйте `@dp.callback_query_handler(text='ans')` и callback будет срабатывать на нажатие кнопки с `callback_data='ans'`

Comment: у меня types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ответить', callback_data=f'{user_id}-ans'). Просто ans не получается